# Unity c# character not stopping after reach the destination

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i'm trying to move my characther with mouse click, everything seems fine right now characther is moving and animation is working. But whenever characther reach the destination point characther keeps walking next to destination point and doing a circle endlessly.
How can i fix that?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class CharacterMoveScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Camera cam;
   public NavMeshAgent player;
   public GameObject targetDest;
   public Animator playerAnimator;
   private string groundTag = "Ground";
private RaycastHit hit;
 private bool isMoving = false;

 void Start()
   {
       player = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
   }


   private void Update()
   {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       {
           Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

           if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
           {
               if (hit.collider.CompareTag(groundTag)) 
               {
                   player.SetDestination(hit.point);
                   isMoving = true;
               }
           }
       }

       UpdateAnimation();
       if (isMoving)
       {
           // Check if the character has reached the destination
           if (!player.pathPending && player.remainingDistance <= player.stoppingDistance)
           {
               if (!player.hasPath || player.velocity.sqrMagnitude == 0f)
               {
                   isMoving = false;
                   player.isStopped = true;
               }
           }
       }

   }


   private void UpdateAnimation()
   {
      
          playerAnimator.SetBool("isWalking", isMoving && player.velocity.magnitude > 0.1f);
     UnityEngine.Debug.Log("is moving" + isMoving);
         UnityEngine.Debug.Log("is stoped" + player.isStopped);
          UnityEngine.Debug.Log(player.pathStatus==NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete);
      
   }
}
```

When game starts ismoving, istoped = false, when i click a destination isMoving becomes true and not stopping when reach the destination

Comment: Make a collider for your 'target' zone, and set a boolean that you've reached the destination using OnTriggerEnter https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: i guess this answer not gonna work like i want

Comment: There are five values govening if the logic `isMoving = false; player.isStopped = true;` is ran every frame, and if it is, then the value might be reset the next frame by a test on three other values. What happens if you breakpoint those values, which specific situations are casuing them to be true or false?

Comment: is moving like always false, is stoped starting false than turning true 
[url=https://www.hizliresim.com/rxuix6d][img]https://i.hizliresim.com/rxuix6d.png[/img][/url]

Comment: @Jay https://www.hizliresim.com/rxuix6d

Comment: Both variables are starting false, when i click only isMoving turning true and nothing happens after that

Comment: @demonjoseph this link ( hizliresim.com/rxuix6d ) is completley meaningless to us without more context. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76157809/edit) your question to include the relavent information

Comment: this is a totally new technology for me , i tried to add breakpoints to code but i guess it is not working real time with game. i can't debug the code

Comment: use debug.log to throw out data at various points, so you can track it real time if thats an issue.  if its circling round a point it suggests it cant get to it, or its moving way too fast and overshoots it constantly..